# Не могу понять логику работы градиента

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть вот такой код градиента:

```css
.test_style7 {
  height: 290px;
  width: 290px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.test27 {
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(red, red 5px, orange 10px, orange 15px, yellow 20px, yellow 25px, green 30px, green 35px, skyblue 40px, skyblue 45px, blue 50px, blue 55px, violet 60px, violet 65px);
}

.test28 {
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(black, black 2px, white 4px, white 6px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS функции: радиальные градиенты</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <div class="test27 test_style7"></div>
    <div class="test28 test_style7"></div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Я только поверхностно, примерно понимаю, как данный код делает четкие переводы между цветами, и смог бы на основе этого примера работать с другими градиентами, но не могу понять это основательно. Зачем, собственно, в записях точки остановки, цвета повторяются? Зачем писать "orange 10px, orange 15px", например? В чем логика этого шага на 5px при записи значений цвета?

Comment: Вдумчиво читайте https://html5book.ru/css3-gradient/#repeating-gradient()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Зачем, собственно, в записях точки остановки, цвета повторяются?

Градиент заполняет элемент в заданном направлении плавными переходами цвета от точки к точке. Если разные точки (а точнее, расстояния от начала градиента) имеют одинаковый цвет, например, "orange 10px, orange 15px", то именно на расстоянии от 10 пикселей до 15 пикселей градиент будет заполнен одним цветом - оранжевым. Удобно и необходимо для задания одноцветных областей и резких переходов, например.

Вот ваш пример:
`red, red 5px, orange 10px, orange 15px, yellow 20px, yellow 25px, green 30px, green 35px, skyblue 40px, skyblue 45px, blue 50px, blue 55px, violet 60px, violet 65px`

Разберем:

```
red,
  <-- от 0 до 5 px заливает одним цветом (красным) -->
red 5px, 
  <-- от 5 до 10 px плавный переход от красного к оранжевому -->
orange 10px, 
  <-- от 10 до 15 px заливает одним цветом (оранжевым) -->
orange 15px, 
  <-- от 15 до 20 px плавный переход от оранжевого к желтому -->
yellow 20px, 
...
и так далее
```

Если вам, к примеру, надо залить элемент в два цвета - чтобы резко чтобы закончился красный и начался синий, нужно будет указать две точки перехода с одним и тем же расстоянием и двумя цветами (см. первый блок в коде). Если этого не сделать, заполнение будет равномерным (см. второй блок). В третьем блоке я сделал точки переходов в 5% от середины (45% и 55% от начала отсчета градиента) - получились и сплошные, и градиентные области в одной заливке:

```css
.papa {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 50%, blue 50%, blue)
}

.mama {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue)
}

.baby {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, red 45%, blue 55%, blue)
}

div {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="papa"></div>
<br>
<div class="mama"></div>
<br>
<div class="baby"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

https://uigradients.com/#Jaipur Здесь можно найти градиент. Справа сверху можно нажать на кнопку </> и скопировать css код. Это не решение но я столько не шарю пока чтобы разобраться в проблеме

Comment: Всяческие генераторы грпдиентов не помогут разобраться в том, как (по какой логике) эти градиенты работают.